# Using grid grid-cols-2 and gap-4 gives a vertical arrangement with gap without a grid

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

so i want to make 4 social media buttons arrange in a grid of 2x2 so i used the tailwind classes `grid grid-cols-2 gap-4` on the parent container of the items. But this just gives me keeps the same top to bottom arrangement of all the items without arranging them in a grid.
Code attached below

```
<div class="social-grid grid col-span-2 gap-4">
            <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter text-5xl"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f text-5xl"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in text-5xl"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram text-5xl"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeEzD.png) is how the web page looks right now

How do i fix this and make the 2x2 grid
I tried a lot of different things but still not able to trouble shoot this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have used `col-span-2` on the grid container element which applies `grid-column: span 2 / span 2`. This would be used on grid **children** to control how they arrange themselves in the grid, not defining the amount of grid columns there are in the grid.

Instead, consider applying `grid-template-columns` to the grid container element which defines the grid columns themselves. As you say, you could add the `grid-cols-2` class name to have a 2×2 grid:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="social-grid grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
    <i class="fab fa-twitter text-5xl"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f text-5xl"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in text-5xl"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="p-5 border-2 border-black rounded-full w-fit ">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram text-5xl"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response!
Tried this and it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you pasted, you aren't using `grid-cols-2`, you are using `col-span-2` which would be used on a child item, not the parent. It seems based on your question you understand this, it may be a simple typo! Changing `col-span-2` to `grid-cols-2`, and also adding `grid-rows-2` in order to achieve the 2x2 effect you are looking for, should solve your problem.

Additionally, you can specify `col-start-1` `col-start-2` `row-start-1` and `row-start-2` on your child items classes  to place them where you would like in the grid.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You were right!
It was just a simple typo
changing it to `grid-cols-2` fixed the issue